# How to generate a diagonals matrix with 2 rows per column in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, matrix, dynamic, diagonal

I'm attempting to put together a dynamic design of experiments generator with corner and face points within an excel macro.

For Example (assuming 3 variables):

Face points have a matrix in the format (so # rows = 2*#vars, cols = #vars)

| Var1 | Var2 | Var3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 0.5 | 0.5 |
| **0** | 0.5 | 0.5 |
| 0.5 | **1** | 0.5 |
| 0.5 | **0** | 0.5 |
| 0.5 | 0.5 | **1** |
| 0.5 | 0.5 | **0** |

Corner Points just have a diagonal matrix (rows/cols = # of variables)

| Var1 | Var2 | Var3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | **1** | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | **1** |

Yes, I can do this pretty simple in Matlab but if I could keep this strictly within excel it would be better. It gets tricky trying to make it dynamic, so instead of just 3 variables, it would be based on a user input (which could be as large as 200). I also want this matrix to be input onto a new sheet starting at C11 for the face points, and then the dynamic row number for the corner points (which start immediately after the face).

Anyone much more versed in vba willing to help?

UPDATE (06/15):

I need to go from:
[image: Blank Matrix]

to:
[image: Filled in Matrix]

Number of Columns = (#) of variables (example is with 3 variables)

number of face point rows = 2*(#) of variables

number of corner point rows = (#) of variables.

(#) of variables is dynamic based on a user input.

Comment: I'd like to help, but your question as currently posted is anything but clear. I read it several times and I still do not understand. Are you looking to transform one table layout dynamically into another? If that is the goal I still can see how it works from what you posted. Please post an image of an Excel worksheet that shows the before and after with just three variables.

Comment: @ExcelHero Added some pictures, does that add some clarification?